# Failed to run python code (using Chaquopy) in AndroidStudio,,,

Tags: python, android

I've tried to run python code in Android Studio but it keeps make Error: FileNotFoundError

```
plt.savefig('C:/Users/userA/Desktop/Project/spam_1.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

I made C:/Users/userA/Desktop/Project directory and want to create and save file name spam1.png

Once i tried it in Jupyter Notebook it didn't make any error but in Android Studio...

Here is Error code

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pbl4_importpython/com.example.pbl4_importpython.MainActivity}: com.chaquo.python.PyException: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/userA/Desktop/Project/spam_1.png'
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/suajj/Desktop/PBL4/spam_1.png'
        at <python>.matplotlib.cbook.to_filehandle(__init__.py:432)
        at <python>.matplotlib.cbook.open_file_cm(__init__.py:447)
        at <python>.contextlib.__enter__(contextlib.py:113)
        at <python>.matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.print_png(backend_agg.py:529)
        at <python>.matplotlib.backend_bases.print_figure(backend_bases.py:2082)
        at <python>.matplotlib.figure.savefig(figure.py:2180)
        at <python>.matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(pyplot.py:722)
        at <python>.myscript.main(myscript.py:53)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:380)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callAttrThrowsNative(chaquopy_java.pyx:352)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrowsNative(Native Method)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrows(PyObject.java:232)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:221)
        at com.example.pbl4_importpython.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0):

An Android app has no direct access to your computer's filesystem, even if it's running in an emulator. So try saving to the app's `files` directory instead, as it says in [the Chaquopy documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-os):

> `os.environ["HOME"]` is set to your app’s [internal storage directory](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific). Any files or subdirectories created in this location will persist until the app is uninstalled.
>
> If your app is [debuggable](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#enable-debug), you can also read and write this directory from Android Studio using the [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer). Its path will be something like `/data/data/your.application.id/files`.